# How to scrape all visible text but exlude text written on hyperlinks?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, python-re

I am interested in all of the visible text of a website.

The only thing is: I would like to exclude hyperlink text. Thereby I am able to exlude text in menu bars because they often contain links. In the image you can see that everything from a menu bar could be excluded (e.g. "Wohnen & Bauen").

[image]
https://www.gross-gerau.de/B%C3%BCrger-Service/Ver-und-Entsorgung/Abfallinformationen/index.php?object=tx,2289.12976.1&NavID=3411.60&La=1

All in all my spider looks like this:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.gross-gerau.de/B%C3%BCrger-Service/Wohnen-Bauen/']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="B%C3%BCrger-Service", deny=deny_list_sm),
                 callback='parse', follow=True),
        )


    def parse(self, response):

        item = {}
        item['scrape_date'] = int(time.time())
        item['response_url'] = response.url

        # old approach 
        # item["text"] = " ".join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//text()").getall()]).strip()
        # exclude at least javascript code snippets and stuff 
        item["text"] = " ".join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//*[name(.)!='head' and name(.)!='script']/text()").getall()]).strip()

        yield item
```

The solution should work for other websites, too.Does anyone have an idea how to solve this challenge? Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Why not extend `[name(.)!='head' and name(.)!='script']` with `name()!='a'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your predicate as

```
[name()!='head' and name()!='script' and name()!='a']
```